# Override MsgBox in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form that requires a user to 'Sign' an excel file before saving. Issue is, I can't save the worksheet if that cell is blank, and I don't want to fill out the form with 'fake data' in order to save the file, as this will prevent the user from being alerted in signing the form.

Ideally I would like a msgbox that has some sort of password input from myself that would bypass this validation that would allow me to save the file when cell C19 is blank when I enter the correct password.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, cancel As 
Boolean)

If Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C19").Value = "(INSERT NAME HERE)" Or Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C19").Value = "" Then
cancel = True
MsgBox "Please input your name in cell C19"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You could turn off the events before you save the file.

Comment: `If Environ$("USERNAME") = "MSauce" Then Exit Sub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will something like this work ?

If you Enter `MSauce` it will save without name, or if you enter any other name it will save and enter that value in `C19`, else it won't save

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, cancel As Boolean)

Dim str As String

str = Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C19").Value

If str = "(INSERT NAME HERE)" Or str = "" Then

    str = InputBox("Please input your name", "Missing Name")

        If str = "MSauce" Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Len(str) > 0 Then
            Application.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C19").Value = str
        Else: cancel = True
        End If


End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thinking out of the box, is there a way to leverage that input from the msgbox and paste it onto cell 'C19'? And exit sub if the str = 'MSAUCE'?